# How to stop the webbrowser from loading content of a page in windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

am developing a windows phone app using web browser control. I have a dashboard from which users can select different urls. When a user selects the url for the first time the browser navigates successfully. But if the user selects another url, the browser waits till the first page loads completely. only after that navigates to the new url. So is there any method to stop the loading of content in a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx), not WebBrowser (that was in Windows Phone 8, not included in 8.1).

The easiest is just to call the [Stop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.stop.aspx) method in your `Tapped` function before navigating to the new URL:

```
myWebView.Stop();
```

It does the following:

> Halts the current WebView navigation or download.

Hope this helps. Good luck.